# Granger Causality test results interpretation

Tags: time-series, python, granger-causality

I've done all the pre-processing on my data and am conducting Granger causality using statsmodels. However, I am confused as to how to interpret the significance of the results when I have multiple lags that reject the Null (pscore <.05), as per example below.  Ideally, I would like to know what the 'optimal' number of lags is in my time series, so that use one time series to predict the future values of the other by 'x' lags. Also note that at 6 lags, the score drops below .05 again - is this somehow significant?

Therefore is it mathematically plausible to simply take the lowest pscore, in this case, that at 2 lags, and say that X2 Granger causes X1 by 2 lags? Then use X2 to predict future values of X1 by 2 lags?

Or, is all I can reasonably say that X2 Granger causes X1, and nothing else?

```
Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 1
ssr based F test:         F=4.2600  , p=0.0421  , df_denom=85, df_num=1
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=4.4104  , p=0.0357  , df=1
likelihood ratio test: chi2=4.3034  , p=0.0380  , df=1
parameter F test:         F=4.2600  , p=0.0421  , df_denom=85, df_num=1

Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 2
ssr based F test:         F=3.4135  , p=0.0377  , df_denom=82, df_num=2
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=7.2434  , p=0.0267  , df=2
likelihood ratio test: chi2=6.9576  , p=0.0308  , df=2
parameter F test:         F=3.4135  , p=0.0377  , df_denom=82, df_num=2

Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 3
ssr based F test:         F=2.2594  , p=0.0880  , df_denom=79, df_num=3
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=7.3788  , p=0.0608  , df=3
likelihood ratio test: chi2=7.0793  , p=0.0694  , df=3
parameter F test:         F=2.2594  , p=0.0880  , df_denom=79, df_num=3

Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 4
ssr based F test:         F=1.5076  , p=0.2084  , df_denom=76, df_num=4
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=6.7444  , p=0.1500  , df=4
likelihood ratio test: chi2=6.4902  , p=0.1654  , df=4
parameter F test:         F=1.5076  , p=0.2084  , df_denom=76, df_num=4

Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 5
ssr based F test:         F=1.4090  , p=0.2312  , df_denom=73, df_num=5
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=8.1064  , p=0.1505  , df=5
likelihood ratio test: chi2=7.7387  , p=0.1712  , df=5
parameter F test:         F=1.4090  , p=0.2312  , df_denom=73, df_num=5

Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 6
ssr based F test:         F=2.2839  , p=0.0452  , df_denom=70, df_num=6
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=16.2484 , p=0.0125  , df=6
likelihood ratio test: chi2=14.8391 , p=0.0215  , df=6
parameter F test:         F=2.2839  , p=0.0452  , df_denom=70, df_num=6
```

Comment: You could choose the lag length using AIC/SIC or choose the number of lags when there is no autocorrelation. From there, you can apply the Granger Causality on that lag length and interpret.

Comment: @SpurEconomics - thankyou! I have done so